# Array Manipulation Hackerrank using python

Tags: python, arrays

This logic is working for most of the test cases but not all. What I am doing wrong?

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries, m):
    li = []
    for j in range(0, m):
        p = queries[j][0]
        r = queries[j][1]
        v = queries[j][2]

        lo = []
        for i in range(0, n):
            lo.append(0)

        for i in range(p - 1, r):
            lo[i] = lo[i] + v

        li.append(lo)

    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(0, n):
            li[i][j] = li[i-1][j] + li[i][j]
    return max(max(li))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    nm = input().split()
    n = int(nm[0])
    m = int(nm[1])

    queries = []
    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = arrayManipulation(n, queries,m)
    print(result)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) this is the problem statement

Comment: Your approach is extremely brute-force. Look for appropriate data structure - segment tree or perhaps Fenwick tree

Comment: When asking questions it's helpful if you refer to the specific problem you are facing. In this case sharing the specific tests that are failing and maybe which part of the code you are most struggling with or any errors you are getting would help others be able to answer more quickly.

Comment: There must be something wrong in this question. In the given link the function only has two parameters, n (the number of elements in your array) and queries (a two dimensional array of queries where each queries[i] contains three integers, a, b, and k).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the python samples pass `m` to `arrayManipulation` as it is not necessary - in python you can just iterate over the list rather than an index of the list:

You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be, you don't need to keep the previous lists just update the one list, e.g.:

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    arr = [0]*n
    for a, b, k in queries:
        for i in range(a-1, b):
            arr[i] += k
    return max(arr)
```

This is still a brute force approach and unlikely to solve challenges from sites like hankerrank that want you to solve these problems more analytically.

So considering this more analytically, you can just consider the endpoints of each query and just have a counter that increments at the start and decrements at the end. Now the challenge just becomes sorting all these starts and ends. So this uses `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to flatten all the `(a, k), (b, -k)` values and `itertools.accumulate()` over the sorted list to providing a running total. Return the `max()` of this, e.g.:

```
import itertools as it

def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    q = it.chain.from_iterable([(a, k), (b, -k)] for a, b, k in queries)
    return max(it.accumulate(c for _, c in sorted(q, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))))
```

Note: you need to sort based on negative `k` or you will subtract before adding at the same endpoint value, which gives the wrong answer, this can be done using the `key` param to `sorted()`. Alternatively, you can invert the `k`s in `q` and then `accumulate(-c ...)` removing the need for the `key` param:

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    q = it.chain.from_iterable([(a, -k), (b, k)] for a, b, k in queries)
    return max(it.accumulate(-c for _, c in sorted(q)))
```

A quick comparison of the 2 approaches using a random `5000` queries over an array of `100000` entries (below the limits of the test, but at the limits of the brute force approach for comparison):

```
Brute force: 19.6 s ± 1.04 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Efficient  : 12.4 ms ± 3.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

At the limits of the test: `2*10**5` queries over `10**7` array length:

```
Efficient  : 891 ms ± 34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Although your algorithm technically is correct, it doesn't pass case 7 through 13 due to timeconstraints. How can we speed up your implementation?

Comment: This won't pass the time constraint and it is not an efficient solution.

Comment: @EbramShehata I wasn't trying to solve the hankerrank problem just simplify the approach the OP was using. Looking at the problem it looks pretty simple to solve, updated answer.

Comment: It passed all tests for me

Answer (score 0):

You're using too many for loops and it can be quickly reduced to only two.

The used approach can be:

1. Define both `maximum_int_value = 0` and `current_int_value = 0`. This first will serve to store the the integer maximum value in the finished array and the current_int_value to store the current maximum.
2. The initial part of the first for can be substituted by something like `li = [0] * n + 1`.
3. Use only two loops - one for calculating the first and last steps in the array and another to get the maximum int value.
4. Calculate sum for each step or fall in the array.
5. If the value of maximum_int_value is lower than current_int_value, then maximum_int_value will be current_int_value.

All in all

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    maximum_int_value = 0
    current_int_value  = 0
    li = [0] * n

    for query in queries:
        li[query[0] - 1] += query[2]
        # edge case taken from here - https://sites.northwestern.edu/acids/2018/11/12/solution-hackerrank-array-manipulation/
        if query[1] != len(li):
            li[query[1]] -= query[2]

    for i in range(len(li)):
        current_int_value  += li[i]
        if maximum_int_value < current_int_value :
            maximum_int_value = current_int_value 

    return maximum_int_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    nm = input().split()

    n = int(nm[0])

    m = int(nm[1])

    queries = []

    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = arrayManipulation(n, queries)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

which will pass all the current 16 Test cases in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem)

[image: It works]

Comment: couldn't pass all. 11 tests failed

Comment: @Mehdi i made it clearer. Check with the current version, I just ran it here and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
def arrayManipulation(arr):
    check = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        check.append(arr[i][1])
    big_jug = max(check) + 1

    temps = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        temps = [[0] * big_jug for _ in range(len(arr))]

    for i in range(len(temps)):
        for j in range(arr[i][0], arr[i][1] + 1):     
            temps[i][j] = arr[i][2]
   
sums = list(map(sum, zip(*temps)))
print(max(sums))
```

first, check for all lower end (i.e:every array, second value of array) to get biggest value of them to create a nested array in which all values are zero.
Then replace all zero values with upper and lower end descrided in all queries(main given array) the and put array third value
The sum all nested list
At last find highest value of the final list

Comment: Code without an explanation isn't that helpful and discouraged on Stack Overflow because it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098) to improve your post's quality. See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference.

Comment: added description

Answer (score 0):

## use this approch due to

for this loop we usesess the variable insted of list it is Due to list take more space than the variable .Therefore  try to use variable

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
arr = [0]*n
for i in queries:
    arr[i[0] - 1] += i[2]
    if i[1] != len(arr):
        arr[i[1]] -= i[2]
k = 0
p = 0
print(arr)
for q in arr:
    p += q
    if p > k:
        k = p
return k
```